# How to access a specific Post parameter in an HTTP Post WebHook?

Tags: c#, http-post, azure-functions, webhooks, jotform

I'm using JotForms to send a POST Message using the WebHook integration. This is the message that is sent.

[RequestBin Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQD0n.png)

I'm implementing a WebService in C# using Azure Functions in order to Insert the values from the form to an SQL-Server.

```
    #r "System.Data"
    using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = "";

    dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.Info(body);

    var e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(body as string);

    name = e.firstname + " " + e.lastname;

    //Connect to SQL

    var cnnString  = "Server=tcp:XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;"+"Initial Catalog=XXXX;"
+"Persist Security Info=False;"+"User ID=XXX;"+"Password=XXXX;"+"MultipleActiveResultSets=False;"
+"Encrypt=True;"+"TrustServerCertificate=False;"+"Connection Timeout=30;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Insert Signup        
        var signupInsert = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_data] ([firstname],[lastname],[date])" +  
        "VALUES ('" + e.q8_FirstName + "','" + e.q9_yTus + "','" + e.q24_Birthday + "')";

        // Execute and load data into database.
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(signupInsert, conn))
        {
            var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    return name == " "
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok" );
    }
}

public class Person{
    public string firstname {get;set;}
    public string lastname {get;set;}
    public string date {get;set;}

    public string q8_FirstName {get;set;}
    public string q9_yTus {get;set;}
    public string q24_Birthday {get;set;}

}
```

I've managed to insert sucessfully when I test with a body that is just the JSON

```
{
    "firstname": "ni\u00f1o",
    "lastname": "Lachner2",
    "date":"08/08/1994",

    "name":"Vincenz2",
    "slug":"submit\/80565829893878\/",
    "input_language":"Espa\u00f1ol",
    "q8_FirstName":"Nombre",
    "q9_yTus":"Apellido",
    "q24_Birthday":"08\/08\/1994",
    "q5_cedula":"115850853",
    "q18_country":"Costa Rica",
    "dropdown_search":"",
    "q3_province":"San Jos\u00e9",
    "q11_cantonSanJose":"Alajuelita",
    "q12_cantonAlajuela":"",
    "q13_cantonHeredia":"",
    "q14_cantonCartago":"",
    "q15_cantonPuntarenas":"",
    "q16_cantonPuntarenas":"",
    "q17_cantonGuanacaste":"",
    "q6_phone":"88141833",
    "q2_mail":"vincenz.lachner@gmail.com",
    "q7_shirtSize":"S",
    "q25_channel":{"0":"Correo electr\u00f3nico","other":"YOU"},
    "q27_politicaDe":"Accepted",
    "preview":"true"

}
```

How can i access the JSON in the rawRequest? That is in the RawBody under the name rawRequest.

and what are these separators? --------------------------e5d83c25c3d6dcc0

```
--------------------------e5d83c25c3d6dcc0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rawRequest"

{"slug":"submit\/80565829893878\/","input_language":"Espa\u00f1ol","q8_FirstName":"textbox_sample0","q9_yTus":"textbox_sample1","q24_Birthday":"11\/11\/1111","q5_cedula":"1","q18_country":"Costa Rica","dropdown_search":"","q3_province":"San Jos\u00e9","q11_cantonSanJose":"Alajuelita","q12_cantonAlajuela":"","q13_cantonHeredia":"","q14_cantonCartago":"","q15_cantonPuntarenas":"","q16_cantonPuntarenas":"","q17_cantonGuanacaste":"","q6_phone":"1","q2_mail":"john@example.com","q7_shirtSize":"XS","q25_channel":["Facebook"],"q27_politicaDe":"Accepted","preview":"true"}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to get here? You are getting the same value as rawRequest when you do `req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`. What difference do you notice between what you get in `body` variable and rawRequest?

Comment: When I test with Postman sending only the JSON with the rawRequest. Everything works out. 

But when I try it with the JotForm integration the result value of
`req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` is what is shown in the RequestBin image.

Printing Out This to the Log

 _[Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp-Sample. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. Newtonsoft.Json: Input string '--------------------------9a42bd911719fe4e' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 42._

Comment: Can you share the details of how are you calling the WebHook from JotForm? Looks like you are posting the entire Form to the WebHook instead of only the JSON data required by the WebHook.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
var form = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
var body = form["rawRequest"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you send the message from JotForms, You could use the following code to get the
rawRequest or you could get pretty property value that is the fields in the JotForms.

The following is my detail steps:

1.Create the JotForms

[image]

2.Add the follow code to get the rawRequest

```
  if (req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
     {
          var content = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
          var test = content.Contents.ToList();
          Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          foreach (var item in test)
          {
              var value = await item.ReadAsStringAsync();
              dic.Add(item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name, value);
              log.Info(value);
          }
          foreach (var item in dic)
          {
             log.Info($"{item.Key}:{item.Value}");
          }
     }
```

3. Remote debug on my side.

[image]